# Second Window - XAML page (UWP app)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have an UWP app in Microsoft/Windows Store, and I have a button (about us button), when I click in this button open a new XAML page above of my XAML home page, with my info, contacts, etc. I have this code for this:

```
CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
int newViewId = 0;
await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.Navigate(typeof(About), null);
    Window.Current.Content = frame;
    // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
    Window.Current.Activate();

    newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
});
bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
```

I want to set a fixed size for this second XAML (About) page and I am using this code:

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(480, 800);
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

but this will affect the size of the application window, and I just wanted the size of this second XAML page (About)

How I make this? Ajust the size of the window only of the about page.

And I liked this second XAML page to appear centered in relation to my main XAML page.

Comment: You should just use a `ContentDialog`. It will be much easier for what you want.

Comment: But I dont want a `ContentDialog`. I want put XAML code in the new window

Comment: Well you could add XAML code to `ContentDialog`. Just when adding a new item to project add Content Dialog and it creates a new XAML and cs files of class that inherits from a `ContentDialog`.