# How do I show a second page that I have created in XAML - UWP C#

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have made a program in WPF previously and am trying to transcirpt it into UWP. However I have come across a barrier.

In WPF you can easily create a new instance of a window and `.Show` that window
For example:

```
    public static SecondGUI_Window secondGUI = new SecondGUI_Window();
    secondGUI.Show();
```

However in UWP I am still confused as how to create a new window. I have tried doing it the same way as in WPF however it doesn't seem to work. I have also viewed and tried a couple of other answers from other stack overflow's

[Second Window - XAML page (UWP app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083048/second-window-xaml-page-uwp-app)

To no avail have I been able to get it working yet.
The main reason I want to have the second screen is so that I can display data on another screen.
For example the second window can  be moved to another screen if the user has two screens.

I would like to keep as much of the usability/flexibility from WPF instancing as possible. For example being able to access the public variables in the window.

When I try and use the code from the example above it gives me an 'await' error.
[Image showing error from visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJz5N.png)

If you need any extra information please ask and I will try my best to provide any information requested.

Any and every help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The errors says your are calling await within a method not marked as async. You can try removing the await keyword from your call. Or you can try moving the logic in your page_load method into another method that returns Task and is marked as async, then you call your new method from page_load method without the await call. This may help... [Call Async Method in Page_Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204450/call-async-method-in-page-load)

Comment: Thank you! From reading that link I could see that all I needed to do was add Async into the calling of the method. (private async void)
I'll post the answer now

Answer (score 0):

From the link provided by [quaabaam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9541862/quaabaam) I have managed to get it working.

From the code in the link I used in my question and some help from you guys I've now managed to have a second window running at the same time.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();              
        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(DisplayWindow), null);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;                
            Window.Current.Activate();
            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
    }
```

Making sure I had the async in the method call, the program now opens a second window.
Now I need to make sure I can get the second window working how I want it to without any issues...